# Ordering products by price in custom wp_query loop

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I currently have a very simple wp_query loop to loop through my WooCommerce products like so:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => $cat,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' =>  'price',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
   $the_query->the_post();
     wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
}
```

This works as I want it to, except I can't get it to order the products by product price (ascending or descending) - what do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'product_cat' => $cat,
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key' => '_price',
    'order' => 'asc'
);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: This is great, are there docs of WooCommerce meta keys around so I don't have to ask here?

Comment: Well this is the link you should have to read https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Meta_Query. Please up vote and accept the answer if it solves your purpose. Thanks!

Comment: this is not working for me, im see a product with 1.50 price, following by one product with 1.30 price...