# Orderby price in a WP_Query for Woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have this code that i need to get all product order by price :

I'm trying to sort my products by price but it doesn't work fine.

This is my code to get products, it works fine if I don't use the "orderby".

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'=> 'product',
    'meta_key' => 'price',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);
$wooCommerceargs = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But the problem is no any product show !

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39205563/ordering-products-by-price-in-custom-wp-query-loop

Answer (score 7):

First, do not use `WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`. From the WooCommerce doc:

> wc_get_products and WC_Product_Query provide a standard way of retrieving products that is safe to use and will not break due to database changes in future WooCommerce versions. Building custom WP_Queries or database queries is likely to break your code in future versions of WooCommerce as data moves towards custom tables for better performance.

See [WooCommerce documentation](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)

Second, you cannot order by price directly in the query. Get your products then call the `wc_products_array_orderby()` function.

```
$args     = array(); // Optional arguments
$products = wc_get_products( $args );
$ordered  = wc_products_array_orderby( $products, 'price', 'ASC' );
```

Answer (score 0):

that works perfectly in 2022

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'product',
'orderby' => '_price',   //price metakey is '_price' !
'order' => 'ASC'
);
$wooCommerceargs = new WP_Query( $args );
```